# What is a Simple Group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

I am working on this problem from class note:

> Let $G'$ be a group and let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$. Assume that $G$ is simple, that $|G| \neq 2$, and that $G'$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of index $2$. Show that $\phi (G) \subseteq N$.

Here are my two questions:

(1) Does the problem referring $G$ as a simple group? What is simple group? I did not see its definition in the text prior this problem. Note this is just a class note and not a commercial-grade textbook, therefore order getting messed up is understandable.

(2) I know that most likely I need to use Lagrange's $|G| = |G/H| \cdot|H|$ and therefore $|H|$ divides $|G|$, and also $G/\ker (\phi) \cong \phi (G)$ and therefore |$G/\ker (\phi)| = |\phi (G)|$, but after those I am lost. A gentle and friendly explanation would therefore be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

**EDIT: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**  
See my own answer after combining hints & helps from *@Tim Raczkowski, @Blah* and others. Thanks for all your time and effort.

Comment: A simple group is a group that has only itself and the zero group as its normal subgroups.

i.e. there are no proper non trivial normal subgroups.

Comment: The kernel of $\phi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Now you can apply the assumption that $G$ is [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group).

Comment: Step 4 is not correct since we don't know $G\subseteq G'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Blah's answer. Let $\sigma\,:G'\to G'/N$ be the canonical homomorphism, and $\psi=\sigma\circ\phi$. Since, $|G'/N|=2$ and $|G|>2$, cannot be injective. So $\ker\psi=G$. In other words, $\psi\left(G\right)=\{eN\}=N$. This implies $\sigma\left(\phi\left(G\right)\right)=N$, which means $\phi\left(G\right)\subseteq N$.

Comment: @Blah gave enough details in the comments under his answer.

Comment: Magnus asked me for some more help on this problem.

Comment: @user26857 : I posted another question yesterday on different problem, to which Tim responded quickly. Since I was very impressed with the way Tim answered my question, I invited him to help with this question as I am still stuck here. If this is not the right way to ask for additional help, all the fault is then mine and not Tim's. Thanks.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski : I hope you will get this message. Even though you were reprimanded for responding to me, but I found yours is friendlier than the other. Two questions though: (1) How do you go from $ker(\psi) = G$ to $\psi (G) = \{eN\} = N$? And (2) How do you arrive at $\sigma (\phi(G)) = N$? Thank you again.

Comment: $\ker(\psi)=G$ means that $\psi$ maps every element of $G$ to the identity of $G'/N$.  If $e$ is the identity of $G'$, then the coset $eN$ is the identity of $G'/N$.  $eN=\{en : n\in N\}=N$ since $en=n$ for all $n\in N$. Now $N=\psi(G)=\sigma\circ\phi(G)$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski : Thanks! I got that part now. But I am still confused when you wrote $\sigma (\phi(G)) = N$ implies that $\phi(G) \subset N$. Does it mean we can generalize that for $f: A \to B$, if $f(A) = B$ then $A \subseteq B$? Thanks again.

Comment: Well $f$ maps every element of $A$ to an element of $B$.  $f(A)$ is the collection of the outputs of $f$ and they must be all elements of $B$ by definition.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski : Tim, see my own answer below after big helps from you. (1) Am I correct in going from (5c) to (5d)? And (2) in your first response, you used the term "canonical," what does it mean intuitively? Thanks again for all your time.

Comment: For $G$ a group, and $N$ a normal subgroup, the map $\phi:G\to G/N$ such that $\phi(g)=gN$ is called the canonical map.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski : Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$
G \rightarrow G' \rightarrow G'/N
$$
is a homomorphism to a group with 2 elements. It's kernel is either $G$ or $\{1\}$ since no other normal subgroups exist

Now you have to use $|G|\neq 2$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am starting to get some headway. Thanks again.

Comment: Your points (5) and (6) are rather simple: if the kernel is $\{1\}\neq G$ then $G\rightarrow G'/N$ is injective and $|G|>2$

Comment: There are so many missing links that stopped me in the middle: (1) How do you know that $G' \to G$? (2) How do you conclude that $|G| > 2$? (3) Once you have established $|G| > 2$, how do you go from there to $\phi G \subseteq N$?

Comment: (2) Well $|G|>2$ because if $|G|=1$ then there is nothing to do and $|G|\neq 2$ is given. (3) There cannot be an injection of a set with more than two elements into a set with two elements.

Answer (score 1):

Having combined all the tips and helps from *@Tim Raczkowski*, *@Blah* and others, here is the wrap-up of what I made up so far:

(1) Let $\phi$ be homomorphism $\phi:G \to G′$ and $\sigma$ be the canonical homomorphis $\sigma:G′ \to G′/N$, and let the composition of two mappings be $\psi = \sigma \cdot \phi$:

$$G \overbrace{\underbrace{\to}_{\phi} G′\underbrace{\to}_{\sigma}}^{\psi} G′/N.$$

(2) Since $|G′/N|=2$ and $|G|\neq 2$, $\psi$ cannot be injective, meaning that $ker(\psi)\neq \{1\}$. 
(3) Since $G$ is simple whose normal subgroup is either $G$ itself or $\{1\}$, and since $ker(\psi)$ is normal subgroup of $G$, therefore it has to be $ker(\psi)=G$.
(4) In other words, $\psi(G)={eN}$, where $e$ is the neutral element of $G'$ and ${eN}$ is the neutral element of $G′/N$, that is, $\psi(G) = \sigma (\phi (G)) = {eN} = N$.
(5) By definition of $\sigma$:

$$\begin{align}
\sigma : G' &\to G'/N \tag{5a}\\
\sigma : \phi(G) &\to \phi(G)/N, \quad  \text{since} \ \phi(G) \subseteq (G) \tag{5b}\\
\sigma : \phi(g) &\mapsto \underbrace{\phi(g)N}_{= \ N}, \quad \forall g \in G \tag{5c}\\
\end{align}$$

(6) From $\phi(g)N = N$ we are forced to conclude that $\phi(g) \in N$, for otherwise $\phi(g)N \neq N$. 
(7) Since $\forall \phi(g) \in \phi(G) \rightarrow \phi(g) \in N$ therefore $\phi(G) \subseteq N. \blacksquare$

Comment: This looks fine to me.