# Mapping Normalizer to Automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am squeezing my brain trying to understand this problem:

> Let H be a subgroup of $G$, and denoted by $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ the group of all automorphisms of $H. $ Define
>
> $$\alpha : N_G(H) \to \operatorname{Aut}(H),\quad g \mapsto \alpha_g.$$
> where $\alpha_g : H \to H, h \mapsto h^g.$ Show that $\alpha$ is a homomorphism and determine $\ker (\alpha).$

I understand that $N_G(H) = \{g \in G : Hg = gH \}$ and that $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ is a set whose elements are automorphisms $\alpha_g : H \to H,$ But what I could not imagine is the mapping from $g$ (element of group $G$) to $\alpha_g$ (which in the most mundane term is actually a function.)

Additionally, I would love to see the synopsis of the solution. Any patient and friendly explanation befitting a person still in learning curve is very much appreciated. Thank you for your time and help. Happy holidays.

Comment: What do you mean you "could not imagine" the mapping from $g$ to $\alpha_g$? You are told what it is in the question.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese : I am sorry if you think my perception is too dumb here: My understanding is that $g$ is element of a group, which in the most mundane term is just number structure, whereas $\alpha_g$ is function in the most mundane term. How could you map a number to a function? Did I miss anything here? Thanks again.

Comment: Given an element $g \in N_G(H)$, you get a homomorphism $H \to H$ $\alpha_g$ given by $h \mapsto ghg^{-1}$; the mapping $\alpha_g$ is entirely determined by $g$. Consider the analogous situation: given any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we get a map $f_a : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_a(x) = x + a$. Sure $a$ is just a number and $f_a$ is a function, but any number corresponds to a function in the aforementioned way.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese : Now I get it with yours and the great responses below. What is the difference between $\to$ and $\mapsto$? Is it that the first one for group and the second for its element? Thanks again and again.

Comment: The arrow $\to$ is used in the indication of the domain and codomain of the map, whereas $\mapsto$ is used to indicate what an element of the domain is mapped to. To illustrate the difference, let me compare with another common notation. One could write $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto x^2$ or instead, $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea:  $\alpha$ is indeed a function.  What that means is that for each element $g \in N_G(H) \le G$, we have a well-defined rule for associating an automorphism of the subgroup $H$, namely conjugation by $g$.

It's important that we only take elements $g$ from the normalizer of $H$, for those are the elements that fix $H$ *setwise* under conjugation.  (This is weaker than fixing $H$ pointwise; i.e. the centralizer of $H$.  More on this later).  In symbols,
$$
N_G(H) = \bigl\{ g \in G \mid gHg^{-1} = H \bigr\},
$$
so the function $\alpha_g$ maps $h \mapsto ghg^{-1} \in H$.

Now to check that $\alpha$ is a **homomorphism,** we have to show that $\alpha(g_1g_2) = \alpha(g_1)\alpha(g_2)$.  Note that the operation on the elements $g_1$ and $g_2$ is in the group $G$; whereas, the operation on the automorphisms $\alpha(g_1)$ and $\alpha(g_2)$ is composition of functions.

*(Hover over the box to reveal the calculation.)*

> $$ \alpha(g_1g_2)(h) = (g_1g_2) h (g_1g_2)^{-1} = g_1g_2 h g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1} = \alpha(g_1)(g_2 h g_2^{-1}) = \alpha(g_1)\bigl(\alpha(g_2)(h)\bigr) $$

What's the **kernel?**  An element $g \in \ker \alpha$ maps to the *trivial* automorphism on $H$ (the identity function).  In other words, $\alpha_g = \alpha_e$.  How do we characterize such $g$?

> $$ \alpha_g(h) = \alpha_e(h) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad ghg^{-1} = ehe^{-1} = h \text{ for all } h \in H \quad\Longrightarrow\quad g \in C_G(H)$$

Comment: I wish I could do more to thank you than just to up-vote you! I have not finished reading it but with the one from Brian I think I am going to see the light. Thank you again and again. PS. (Rather sheepishly) Do you mind if you also give me a hand on this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068944/what-is-a-simple-group ?

Answer (score 3):

$N_G(H)$ is a group — specifically, a subgroup of $G$. $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ is also a group: it’s elements are functions — specifically, automorphisms of $H$ — and its operation is composition of functions. Thus, the function $\alpha$ that assigns to each $g\in N_G(H)$ the automorphism $\alpha_g\in\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ defined by $\alpha_g(h)=h^g$ for each $h\in H$ is simply a function from one group to another; don’t let the fact that the elements of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ are themselves functions get in your way.

Since $\alpha$ is a function from one group to another, it could conceivably be a homomorphism, and our task is to show that in fact it is one. In other words, we need to show that for any $g_0,g_1\in G$, $$\alpha_{g_0g_1^{-1}}=\alpha_{g_0}\circ\alpha_{g_1}^{-1}\;.\tag{1}$$

The two sides of $(1)$ are functions from $H$ to $H$; to show that they’re equal, we must show that

$$h\alpha_{g_0g_1^{-1}}=h\left(\alpha_{g_0}\circ\alpha_{g_1}^{-1}\right)$$

for each $h\in H$. (Here I’m writing the function after its argument.) Let $h\in H$; then

$$\begin{align*}
h\alpha_{g_0g_1^{-1}}&=h^{g_0g_1^{-1}}\\
&=(g_0g_1^{-1})^{-1}h(g_0g_1^{-1})\\
&=g_1g_0^{-1}hg_0g_1^{-1}\\
&=g_1h^{g_0}g_1^{-1}\\
&=(h^{g_0})^{g_1^{-1}}\\
&=(h\alpha_{g_0})\alpha_{g_1^{-1}}\\
&=h(\alpha_{g_0}\circ\alpha_{g_1^{-1}})\;,
\end{align*}$$

and $\alpha$ is indeed a homomorphism.

The identity element of $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ is the identity map $\operatorname{id}_H$ from $H$ to $H$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\ker\alpha&=\{g\in N_G(H):\alpha_g=\operatorname{id}_H\}\\
&=\{g\in N_G(H):h^g=h\text{ for all }g\in H\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

With just a little more work you should be able to translate that definition into a familiar subgroup of $H$.

Comment: I wish I could do more to thank you than just to up-vote you! I have not finished reading it but with the one from Sammy I think I am going to see the light. Thank you again and again. PS. (Rather sheepishly) Do you mind if you also give me a hand on this question: math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068944/what-is-a-simple-group   ?

Comment: @A.Magnus: I’ll take a look.

Comment: @A.Magnus: I can’t add much to Blah’s answer there. $G'/N$ is a group, since $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G'$, and $|G'/N|=2$, since $N$ has $2$ cosets in $G'$ (because it’s of index $2$). $\psi:G'\to G'/N:g'\mapsto g'N$ is a homomorphism by basic facts about quotient groups. Thus, $\psi\circ\varphi:G\to G'/N$ is a homomorphism from $G$. $G$ is simple, so $\ker(\psi\circ\varphi)$ is $\{1_G\}$ or $G$. It can’t be $\{1_G\}$, because then $G\cong G'/N$ and $|G|=2$, so it must be $G$. If $\psi(g)\notin N$ for some $g\in G$, then $\varphi(\psi(g))$ is not the identity of $G'/N$, and ...

Comment: ... $g\notin\ker(\psi\circ\varphi)$, which is a contradiction. Thus, $\psi(g)\in N$ for all $g\in G$.

Answer (score 2):

just assume that $H=G$ for now.  $G$ acts on itself by conjugation, and conjugation by an element is an automorphism of $G$.  if $\alpha_g:G\to G$ is conjugation by $g$, we have
$$
a_{g_1g_2}(h)=(g_1g_2)h(g_1g_2)^{-1}=\alpha_{g_1}(\alpha_{g_2}(h)),
$$
i.e. $\alpha:G\to\text{Aut}(G)$, $g\mapsto\alpha_g$, is a homomorphism (the group operation on automorphisms is composition of functions).  the kernel of $\alpha$ is the set
$$
\{g\in G : \alpha_g\equiv 1_G\},
$$
which is a way of describing $Z(G)$, the center of $G$ (the elements of $G$ that commute with everything).

Now you should be able to generalize this to a subgroup and it's normalizer.

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could do more than just up-vote you guys!