# Group Transitive Action's Effect on Stabilizers's Conjugacy

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking for guidance for two problems on group action, one of them is here and the other one has just been posted earlier:

> Assume that $G$ operates on a set $\Omega.$ Show that, if $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega,$ then all one-point-stabilizers of $G$ are conjugate.

In the class note, $G_\omega$ is stabilizer defined as $G_\omega : = \{g \in G : \omega g = \omega \} ,$ and then $G$ is said to act *transitively* on $\Omega,$ if there exists an element $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $\omega G = \Omega.$

Here are what I have managed so far:
$$\omega G = \Omega$$
$$G_\omega : = \{g \in G : \omega g = \omega \}$$
$$\Rightarrow \Omega g = \Omega$$
$$\Rightarrow \omega G = \Omega g$$
$$ ... $$
$$ ... $$

But again as in the first problem I am stuck here because, I think, my understanding of group action is not fluid enough. I would appreciate any help to give me good understanding of group action. Thanks for your time and help, for this problem as well as the previous one.

PS. My class note defines group action as follow: Let $G$ and $\Omega$ be a group and a non-empty set, we say that $G$ acts (or operates) on $\Omega$ if there exists a homomorphism $\phi$ from $G$ to $Sym(\Omega).$ Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\omega_1,\omega_2\in\Omega$. Since, the group action is transitive, there is a $g\in G$ such that $\omega_1g=\omega_2$. It should follow fairly easily that $G_{\omega_2}=g^{-1}G_{\omega_1}g$.

Claim: $g^{-1}G_{\omega_1}g\subseteq G_{\omega_2}$

Let $h\in g^{-1}G_{\omega_1}g$. So, $h=g^{-1}kg$ for some $k\in G_{\omega_1}$.

Now, $\omega_2h=\omega_2\left(g^{-1}kg\right)=\omega_1kg=\omega_1g=\omega_2$. So, $h\in G_{\omega_2}$.

Claim: $G_{\omega_2}\subseteq g^{-1}G_{\omega_1}g$

Let $h\in g^{-1}G_{\omega_2}g$, and $k=ghg^{-1}$.

$$\omega_1k=\omega_1\left(ghg^{-1}\right)=\omega_2hg^{-1}=\omega_2g^{-1}=\omega_1.$$

So, $k\in G_{\omega_1}$ and since, $h=g^{-1}kg$, then $h\in g^{-1}G_{\omega_1}g$.

Comment: If your will, could you please break down the steps from $\omega_1 g = \omega_2$ to $G_{\omega_2} = gG_{\omega_1}g^{-1}$? Unfortunately, what you think "fairly easy" is anything but easy for me. :-) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: OK. I've filled in the details for you.

Comment: Thank you and may your reputation takes LEAPS and BOUNDS going forward! I think there are typos here in (a) the 3rd. paragraph from top, $k \in G$ should be $k \in G_{\omega_1}$ instead, and also in (b) 6th paragraph "Let $h \in g^{-1}G_{\omega_2}g$..." should be "Let $h \in G_{\omega_2}$..." instead. Thank you again.

Comment: To Tim Raczkowski: Would you mind helping me with this old posting? I am asking this sheepishly. :-) I got only bits and pieces and up to now I still could not make ends meet. Do you have simple way of solving it? Thanks again and again. Link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068944/what-is-a-simple-group

Comment: I'll take a look soon.

Comment: Thanks! I got your posting and I also posted a message to user26857, telling him that I did ask you to give me new insight into that problem and if he considers that is not the right way to ask for additional help, all faults are mine and not yours. Thanks again and again for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $\;G\;$ acts on a set $\;X\;$ , then for $\;x,y\in X\;$ , we have that

$$y\in \mathcal Orb(x)\implies y =xg\implies G_y=gG_xg^{-1}$$

Now, how many orbits do you have in your question? End the argument.